# What is the value of $repositoryLocationName when running ExecutePipeline in Dagster's GraphQL API?

Tags: graphql, dagster

I am attempting to launch a Dagster pipeline run with the GraphQL API. I have Dagit running locally and a working pipeline that I can trigger via the playground.

However, I am now trying to trigger the pipeline via GraphQL Playground, available at `/graphql`.

I am using the following mutation:

```
mutation ExecutePipeline(
  $repositoryLocationName: String!
  $repositoryName: String!
  $pipelineName: String!
  $runConfigData: RunConfigData!
  $mode: String!
)
```

...and hence am providing the following query params:

```
{
  "repositoryName": "my_repo",
  "repositoryLocationName": <???>,
  "pipelineName": "my_pipeline",
  "mode": "dev",
  "runConfigData": {<MY_RUN_CONFIG>}
}
```

I am not sure what value `repositoryLocationName` should take? I have tried a few but receive the following error:

```
{
  "data": {
    "launchPipelineExecution": {
      "__typename": "PipelineNotFoundError"
    }
  }
}
```

[This](https://docs.dagster.io/overview/graphql-api#main) is the tutorial I am following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Each repository lives inside a repository location. Dagster provides a default repository location name if you do not provide one yourself. To find the location name, you can click the repository picker in Dagit, and it'll be next to the repository name:

[image]

In this example, the repository name is `toys_repository`, and the location name is `dagster_test.toys.repo`

**Longer answer:**

A workspace (defined with your `workspace.yaml`) is a collection of repository locations.

There are currently three types of repository locations:

- Python file
- Python module
- gRPC server

Each repository location can have multiple repositories. Once you define the location, Dagster is able to automatically go find all the repositories in that location. In the example above, I defined my workspace to have a single Python module repository location:

```
load_from:
  - python_module: dagster_test.toys.repo
```

Note that simply specified a module and did not specify a repository location name, so Dagster assigned a default repository location name.

If I wanted to specify a location name, I would do:

```
load_from:
- python_module:
    module_name: dagster_test.toys.repo
    location_name: "my_custom_location_name"
```

Similarly for a python file location:

```
load_from:
- python_file: repo.py
```

Or with a custom repository location name:

```
load_from:
- python_file:
    relative_path: repo.py
    location_name: "my_custom_location_name"
```

Comment: If we did not put our job into a repository, what do we put for the values of those two fields? `repositoryName` and `repositoryLocation`?

Answer (score 0):

You can also find out using a GraphQL query. Starting from the example [provided in the documentation](https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/dagit/graphql#get-a-list-of-pipelines-runs), you just need to add

```
repositoryOrigin {
      repositoryLocationName
    }
```

resulting in

```
query PaginatedPipelineRuns {
  pipelineRunsOrError {
  __typename
     ... on PipelineRuns {
           results {
             runId
             pipelineName
             status
             runConfigYaml
             repositoryOrigin {
                repositoryLocationName
             }
          stats {
            ... on PipelineRunStatsSnapshot {
              startTime
              endTime
              stepsFailed
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This will return the repository location name for any run that is returned. Trigger the pipeline that you want the location name for in the UI before querying and that run will be your first result.